# Can you identify this axle coupling?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Can you identify this piece. It can be used to join 2 axles together and I'd like to order more.  I've also seen some without the cross shape inside which I think can join bars together.

side view
[image: side view]

top view
[image: top view]

Answer (score 8):

Looks like [*Part #6538c - Technic, Axle Connector 2L (Smooth with x Hole + Orientation).*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6538c&name=Technic,%20Axle%20Connector%202L%20(Smooth%20with%20x%20Hole%20%20%20Orientation)&category=%5BTechnic,%20Connector%5D#T=C)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can these axle connectors work with bars? If not, is there a part that will?

Comment: The usual 3.18 mm bar? It will work fine with 6538a and 6538c. Not as strong compared to Technic axle, but will work.